# How do I copy and paste values and formats to a new worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the values and format from Sheet1 to Sheet2 but I am not having much luck. The code works fine but only pastes the Value

I tried using xlPasteFormats with xlPasteValues and I keep getting errors.

```
    Private Sub TransferButton_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Dim copySheet As Worksheet
      Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

      Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
      Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")


  copySheet.Range("A1:G29").Copy

  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial 
  Paste:=xlPasteAll
  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial 
  Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths

  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

      Range("D5").Value = Range("D5").Value + 1

        Range("A8").ClearContents
        Range("B8").ClearContents
        Range("C8").ClearContents
        Range("D8").ClearContents
        Range("A10").ClearContents
        Range("A13").ClearContents
        Range("B13").ClearContents
        Range("C13").ClearContents
        Range("D13").ClearContents
        Range("A15").ClearContents
        Range("B15").ClearContents
        Range("C15").ClearContents
        Range("C15").ClearContents
        Range("A17").ClearContents
        Range("C17").ClearContents
        Range("A20:D24").ClearContents
        Range("D25").ClearContents
        Range("A28").ClearContents
        Range("B28").ClearContents
        Range("C28").ClearContents

    End Sub
```

I expect the pasted range from sheet1 to be copied and pasted into sheet 2 with the same values, colours, fonts (Formats) e.c.t.

Comment: "I tried using xlPasteFormats with xlPasteValues" - can you show how you tried?

Comment: @BigBen I tried doing it as seen below:

  copySheet.Range("A1:G29").Copy
  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
  .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

Comment: @Whitena can you please add code by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58592962/edit)? It can be hard to parse otherwise

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad amended

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dim copySheet As Worksheet
  Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

  Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

  copySheet.Range("A1:G29").Copy
  With pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
  End With

'You can assign the height of a row to different rows if xlPasteFormats does not do it for you
      height = copySheet.Range("A5").Height
      pasteSheet.Range("A1:G29").RowHeight = height

     End Sub
```

Comment: This works but It is not setting the width or height of the cell from Sheet1. Also, it brings in any formulas from sheet1 to sheet2.

Comment: Not working, I am simply after a VBA piece of code that can simply place a page break once you run the code each time. Basically think of it as an invoice, copy the invoice and paste it in a new row but add a page break so when we go to print it will have all the format and correct details on the invoice and not overlaping invoices.